# JavaScript: Prevent iOS keyboard + url bar from covering content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

I have the following DOM layout:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#scroll-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <input placeholder='Hi' autofocus>
  <div id='scroll-container'>
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
    <div>25</div>
    <div>26</div>
    <div>27</div>
    <div>28</div>
    <div>29</div>
    <div>30</div>
    <div>31</div>
    <div>32</div>
    <div>33</div>
    <div>34</div>
    <div>35</div>
    <div>36</div>
    <div>37</div>
    <div>38</div>
    <div>39</div>
    <div>40</div>
    <div>41</div>
    <div>42</div>
    <div>43</div>
    <div>44</div>
    <div>45</div>
    <div>46</div>
    <div>47</div>
    <div>48</div>
    <div>49</div>
    <div>50</div>
    <div>51</div>
    <div>52</div>
    <div>53</div>
    <div>54</div>
    <div>55</div>
    <div>56</div>
    <div>57</div>
    <div>58</div>
    <div>59</div>
    <div>60</div>
    <div>61</div>
    <div>62</div>
    <div>63</div>
    <div>64</div>
    <div>65</div>
    <div>66</div>
    <div>67</div>
    <div>68</div>
    <div>69</div>
    <div>70</div>
    <div>71</div>
    <div>72</div>
    <div>73</div>
    <div>74</div>
    <div>75</div>
    <div>76</div>
    <div>77</div>
    <div>78</div>
    <div>79</div>
    <div>80</div>
    <div>81</div>
    <div>82</div>
    <div>83</div>
    <div>84</div>
    <div>85</div>
    <div>86</div>
    <div>87</div>
    <div>88</div>
    <div>89</div>
    <div>90</div>
    <div>91</div>
    <div>92</div>
    <div>93</div>
    <div>94</div>
    <div>95</div>
    <div>96</div>
    <div>97</div>
    <div>98</div>
    <div>99</div>
    <div>100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To see the issue with this page, you'll need to open that fiddle (or [this one, if you prefer codepen](https://codepen.io/duhaime/full/poOLRWz)) in full screen view mode.

If you scroll to the bottom with a web browser, there's no issue, you can scroll down to #100.

However, if you scroll to the bottom with an iOS device, you get stuck, and can't scroll all the way to #100. I can only make it to #91 on an iPhone SE:

[image]

If the keyboard is open, I can only make it to #84:

[image]

I've read a number of threads that try to work around these problems but have not encountered a valid solution yet.

Does anyone know how I can make the page scroll down to #100 in both cases? I'd be grateful for any pointers!